# The knife paradox?

Tags: encryption

In one of the hot forums of today on how to convince friends cryptography is good one of the arguments stated is the knife paradox, I was unable to find the answer on Google and my question is what is the knife paradox?

Comment: Where did you see this? Maybe a variant of [the wrench attack](https://xkcd.com/538/)?

Comment: Or https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber-hose_cryptanalysis

Comment: I think the OP is referring to one of the current hot secse questions: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/123252/71460

Comment: I ended up here after doing exactly the same. I believe the so called "knife paradox" isn't actually an established thing (nor a paradox), but just a thought. If anything, it is an example of a logical fallacy (which one, however, currently escapes me). The idea is basically, "knives are used by criminals, ergo knives are bad/dangerous". Apply the same flawed logic to "encryption".